# How to profile CLR stored procedure

Tags: .net, visual-studio, profiler, clrstoredprocedure

guys!
I have stored procedure, written on C# using Visual Studio 2010. It is running very slow and I want to profile it to detect slowness source. I have JetBrains dotTrace profiler and built-in Visual Studio profiler, but have no idea, how to attach any of these great tools to CLR stored procedure. 
Any suggestions, how it could be done?
Thanks.

Comment: What database are you running?

Comment: I suggest you post the code of the CLR stored proc

Comment: Actually it is SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition, but also I have access to 2008 R2 if it does matter.

Comment: @Mitch it is under NDA. but there are no any special code - just a regular procedure, which validates record in database using application specific logic, and I believe, that this code will not be helpful for this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be useful for someone: you can profile CLR stored procedure, simply by creating executable that calls that procedure static method and profile this executable using one of existing profilers for .Net applications. I've used dotTrace.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Red Gate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) has built-in SQL profiling that may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach with your profiler to sqlservr.exe and see what you want